# How to return a promise in sequelize QueryInterface?

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I apologize if it is a naive question but I am new to sequelize and i am trying to talk to database using QueryInterface.

```
module.exports = {
  up: function (queryInterface, Sequelize) {
    queryInterface.addIndex(
      'entry',
      ['create_date', 'username'],
      {
        indexName: 'create_date_username'
      }
    );

    queryInterface.addIndex(
      'entry',
      ['username'],
      {
        indexName: 'username'
      }
    );

    queryInterface.addIndex(
      'entry',
      ['source_id', 'source_type'],
      {
        indexName: 'source_id_source_type'
      }
    ) 
    .then(() =>
    Promise (
      ????
    )
  ); 
 }, 

  down: function (queryInterface, Sequelize) {
    queryInterface.removeIndex('entry', 'create_date_username');
    queryInterface.removeIndex('entry', 'username');
    queryInterface.removeIndex('entry', 'source_id_source_type');
  }
};
```

But i am getting an `ERROR: Migration 20112-Add-Indices.js (or wrapper) didn't return a promise.` But i am new to it and not sure how to exactly return a promise. Can someone assist me with it please. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot the return statement. Try something like this:

```js
up: function (queryInterface, Sequelize) {
    return Promise.all([
        queryInterface.addIndex(
          'entry',
          ['create_date', 'username'],
          {
            indexName: 'create_date_username'
          }
        ),
        queryInterface.addIndex(
          'entry',
          ['username'],
          {
            indexName: 'username'
          }
        ),
        queryInterface.addIndex(
          'entry',
          ['source_id', 'source_type'],
          {
            indexName: 'source_id_source_type'
          }
        )
    ])
    .then(() => ...
```

Comment: What are you supposed to do with the return value?

Comment: Thank you. Promise.all worked as mentioned above.

Comment: However, i am getting this : `ERROR: Duplicate key name 'create_date_username'`. Any idea on how to solve it?

Comment: Looks like you try to add existing index

Comment: Yup. You're exactly right, i Changed the indexname for each field to something else. I am good. Appreciate all the help brother!!

Answer (score 0):

Try it

```
module.exports = {
    async up(queryInterface, Sequelize) {
        await queryInterface.addIndex('entry', ['create_date', 'username'], {
            indexName: 'create_date_username'
        });

        await queryInterface.addIndex('entry', ['username'], {
            indexName: 'username'
        });

        await queryInterface.addIndex('entry', ['source_id', 'source_type'], {
            indexName: 'source_id_source_type'
        });
    },

    async down(queryInterface, Sequelize) {
        await queryInterface.removeIndex('entry', 'create_date_username');
        await queryInterface.removeIndex('entry', 'username');
        await queryInterface.removeIndex('entry', 'source_id_source_type');
    }
};
```